# How do you make a function read form a txt file and store random lines in a variable?

Tags: php, loops, random

How do you make a function read form a txt file and store random lines in a variable? It will be run over and over in a foreach loop. The language is PHP.

Im a new coder so I don't know things like this off the top of my head.

Comment: There have got to be billions of examples of this out there by now.

Comment: From the FAQ: Treat others with the same respect you'd want them to treat you. We're all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know. Bring your sense of humor.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do it:

```
$contents = file('myfile.txt');
shuffle($contents);
array_splice($contents, 5);

var_dump($contents);
```

1. Reads the whole file into an array
2. Shuffles the array
3. Cuts the array off after 5 elements

Now you have an array of 5 randomly chosen strings.

This method simple, but rather inefficient if the file is very big.

Comment: I think by "insufficient" you mean "inefficient". ;)

Comment: @musicfreak I think I do, too. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
// read the file
$file = file_get_contents( $path );

// convert to array of lines (assuming \n is delimiter)
$lines = explode( "\n" , $file );

// put lines in random order
shuffle( $lines );

// grab the first few lines or whatever you need
$random_lines = array_slice( $lines , 0 , 10 );
```

Comment: loading the file with `file` instead of `file_get_contents` saves you the `explode`.

Comment: yes, file is a much better choice for this, especially with the FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES and possibly FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES options.

Answer (score 2):

```
$file = file( $path );
shuffle( $file );
$random_lines = array_slice( $lines , 0 , 20 ); #first 20 lines
```